# Select text of PDF on Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I need to select the text on PDF drawing have already loaded into Forge Viewer. My cursor always show as hand icon **(on pan tool)** when i try to select these text. Is it possible to select text and get the content from it on Viewer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the native `Text Selection` tool: when loading a native PDF file containing text, the toolbar will include a "Text Selection" button that allows to select and copy text in the PDF - this feature is available since `v7.1`:

[image]

**UPDATE**

You don't need to explicitly load the PDF extension script - tested below and worked well to load multiple PDFs:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/style.min.css?v=v7.*" type="text/css">
  <script language="JavaScript" src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=v7.*"></script>

//...

const mat4 = new THREE.Matrix4()
mat4.makeTranslation(10,10,10) //Apply translation manually to position the PDFs if necessary

Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer({env: 'Local'}, ()=>{
//...
  viewer.start('path/to/pdf');
  viewer.loadModel('path/to/pdf', {placementTransform:mat4});
//...
```

[image]

Comment: Thank for your answer, it work fine for me and i can select the text when i upgrade to version 7.* but the problem is that I can not open multiple PDF file in the same viewer. I try to load 2 files PDF into viewer but it only show 1 model pdf , eventually when the console out still see 2 models in there. When i switch back to viewer 7.0 it work fine but have problem with viewer higher than 7.0 . Do you know what wrong here ?

Comment: ** 0: u {visibleBoundsDirty: true, enforceBvh: false, id: 3, getGeometryList: ƒ, getFragmentList: ƒ, …}
1: u {visibleBoundsDirty: false, enforceBvh: false, id: 4, getGeometryList: ƒ, getFragmentList: ƒ, …} ** This is the 2 model i got from getVisibleModels()

Comment: When I tried to load multiple PDFs with v7.4 I could see them both - were those PDFs overlapped for you so there was only one of them visible?

Comment: My setting  :      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.4.1/style.min.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.4.1/viewer3D.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.4.1/extensions/PDF/PDF.js"></script>

Comment: And one more thing is that it only work when i change it back to something like this :     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.0.*/style.min.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.0.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.0.*/extensions/PDF/PDF.js"></script>

Comment: Hi Bryan, my code is get all the PDF already loaded into a viewer and hide/show these models by this function viewer.hideModel(modelId) / viewerPDF.showModel(modelId) . My function to load the model is viewer.loadModel('filePath', viewer) . I have tried so many times with a lot of changing but notthing better, it only load the first PDF file. I have no idea where is the problem . Can you please help

Comment: see update in the answer - going forward start a new thread for another question

Comment: The problem is that i put the viewer as the second parameter on this function when load model viewer.loadModel(pdf, viewer) , when i remove this parameter it work fine. Thank you very much for your help !